# Concatenate two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, concatenation, push

how to add two arrays if the condition were,

1. longer array should be appended to the shorter array.
2. If both arrays are equally long, the second array should be appended to the first array.

For example: `concatUp([1, 2], [3])` should return `[3, 1, 2]` and `concatUp([5, 7], [6, 8])` should return `[5, 7, 6, 8]`.

here is my code:

```js
function concatUp(a1, a2) {
  var list = a1,
    a2;
  var arrLen1 = a1.length;
  var arrLen2 = a2.length;
  if (a1 > a2) {
    a2.concat(a1);
  } else if (a1 < a2) {
    a1.concat(a2);
  } else {
    a1.push(a2);
  }
  return list;
}
console.log(concatUp([1, 2], [3]));
console.log(concatUp([5, 7], [6, 8]));
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.concat` does not mutate the inputs, but returns a new array, which is the concatenation. You need to do something with the value yielded from `a2.concat(a1);` etc. Refer to the MDN: ["The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: What's your logic on this line `var list = a1, a2;`?

Comment: And had a hunch that this question seemed too formal. Found it asked here https://www.jshero.net/en/koans/concat.html

Answer (score 1):

probably you want something like this

```js
function concatUp(arr1,arr2){
  return arr1.length>arr2.length ?[...arr2,...arr1]:[...arr1,...arr2]
}

console.log(concatUp([1, 2], [3]));
console.log(concatUp([5, 7], [6, 8]))
```

Comment: Nice with the 3 dots notation.